# How to replace values of a CSV field using Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I have the following requirements:

1. For each record in a CSV file, read the value contained in three of its fields named `startValue`, `endValue` and `change`.
2. Calculate the `change` as (endValue-startValue)/startValue
3. Compare the calculated `change` to the `change` provided in the CSV file for the record. Log a warning if different to the same number of decimal places. Continue to step 4 in any case.
4. Replace the `change` value in the CSV file with the `change` calculated in step 3. Leave the CSV file unaltered otherwise. Blank lines, line terminators, headers and all other field values should remain unchanged.

I'm aware of two approaches.

**Approach 1**

```
from("{{route.getCsvFile}}")
.unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(MyValueChange.class))`
.process(myProcessor) // calculates `change` and replaces CSV `change` value
.to("bean-validator:changeValidator") // does step 3
.marshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(MyValueChange.class))
.to("{{route.putCsvFile}}");
```

The problem: I do not want to have to unmarshall all CSV fields into a Java object. I only need the three fields to work with `change`. The CSV file contains 75 other fields.

**Approach 2**

```
from("{{route.getCsvFile}}")
.unmarshal(new CsvDataFormat())
.process(myProcessor)
.marshal(new CsvDataFormat())
.to("{{route.putCsvFile}}");
```

The problem: `myProcessor` must now contain code to parse through a `List` of `String`s and must contain code to validate the bean (instead of using Camel's call to bean validation).

Is there a way to use bindy for just three fields and then use that bean to replace only the `change` values within the original CSV data?